# Filtered Products not re-rendering in react but re-rendering in the state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-context

I am trying to filter products in my products array. the state is showing filtered products but the component is not re-rendering.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Search from "./SearchBox";
import { storeProducts } from "../data";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";

export default class Store extends Component {
 constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  campaign: storeProducts,
  searchfield: ""
    };
}
onChange = e => {
this.setState({ searchfield: e.target.value });
console.log(e.target.value);
};
render() {
const searchStore = this.state.campaign.filter(storeProducts => {
  return storeProducts.title
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
});
console.log(searchStore);
return (
  <div>


 <div className="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-6">
          <StoreBanner className="banner_area">
            <Search onchange={this.onChange}/>
          </StoreBanner>
        </div>
      </div>
    </SearchArea>

    <ProductList storeProducts={searchStore} />

  </div>
);
```

My product List component is this, i am making use of react context api.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import Title from "./Title";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../Context";
export default class ProductList extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <React.Fragment>

    <div className="py-5">
      <div className="container">
        <Title className="font-weight-bold" name="Our" title=" Products" />
        <div className="row">
          <ProductConsumer>
            {value => {
              return value.products.map(product => {
                return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
              });
            }}
          </ProductConsumer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

}
}

when i search, the console shows the  correct number of objects in the array but the products do not re-render. please i need help on this, i have been on it for days. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you put let instead of const searchStore?

Comment: What does `storeProducts={searchStore}` prop for `ProductList` do? I don't see that prop used in your snippet.

Comment: No changes, still no re-rendering

Comment: @Drew Reese, storeProduct is all my products in the state, searchStore is the filtering logic

Comment: I asked about the prop `storeProducts`, plural, a prop you are passing to `ProductList`, I don't see it used in your snippet. And `searchStore` isn't the filtering logic, *it is* the filtered data being passed to prop `storeProducts`. Inside `ProductList` I see you mapping `value.products` from your consumer. Is there something actually updating the context provider?

Comment: Would it be simpler to pass `searchfield` as a prop to `ProductList` and just filter the products data there on the fly before rendering it? What happens when the searchfield filter is cleared, how do you get back to unfiltered products data? Generally with filtering you don't want to mutate your data source.

Comment: @Drew Reese storeProducts is imported from the data on my machine, it is the same data passed to my state, filtered and passed as props. and besides, do you think there is a mistake there? kindly get back to me

Comment: That's what I'm driving at, the passed prop isn't being used in the snippet you shared where you map products. Can you share *more* (or all) of the `ProductList` component code so we can see what you do with that passed `storeProducts` prop? Otherwise, share how your product context is updated (or not) where the `value.products` should have been updated to rerender?

Comment: Sincerely i do not understand what you mean by passing searchfield as a prop to ProductList before rendering it. i have used the same method on other  project and they work, kindly expatiate more on what you mean.

Comment: i will share the product page, thats all on the product lList. now i understand what you mean by the prop is not used

Comment: i just looked through all, i didn't make use of the prop, the data is a static data in a data.js file, and i actually thought putting the searchStore will automatically re-render it

Comment: @ Drew Reese, where can i make use of the searchStore? or what can i do?

Comment: this is the online demo of the store https://zinnfood.netlify.com/store

Comment: @D.B.J Can you produce a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example to [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: LInk is 404. Can you update your question to include the `ProductList` component?

Comment: i just updated the ProductList component, sorry about the broken link, this link should work https://zinnfront.netlify.com/store  i tried producing an example on code sandbox, the code was breaking.